# Keybindings specific to a certain buffer

Tags: emacs

I use a mode (merlin, but that doesn't matter) which opens a buffer with the name `*merlin-type*` when displays type information in it. I'd like to be able to type `q` in that buffer to close it. There's no mode specific to the buffer that I can hook into; what I'd like to do is create a buffer-local keybinding; how do I do this/what else should I be doing?

Comment: A little confused - you say you run a mode - how is the mode you run defined? Are there any mode hooks defined? If so, you can create a mode specific keymap and use that to bind q locally to quit the mode. There isn't enough detail to be more specific.

Comment: The buffer which is opened by merlin (on C-c C-t) does not run merlin mode itself. It's just a message buffer containing the types of the form at my point. No hooks as far as I know get called when this types buffer is opened. The only thing I can think of is that is has a consistent name.

Comment: Just a thought: Could you derive an appropriate mode yourself and add an entry to `auto-mode-alist` that puts the buffer in that mode?  Not sure if that's the right way to handle this, but it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: @AaronHarris that's definitely a good option, but if there's a less heavyweight way to do this, I'd prefer to not create a minor mode.

Comment: What you want to do is likely very simple. The problem is understanding your environment in order to know how to do this. Normally, the buffer would have a local keymap or a mode specific keymap and you could then just define-key an unused key to close the buffer. Have you done a C-h b to list all the bindings available when your in the buffer - might provide a clue as to where to put the key binding so it is only active in that buffer. An apropos for *-map might also prove useful as would apropos for Merlin.  How/where is the C-c C-t key binding defined?

Comment: @TimX I'd already checked for modes, as mentioned in the question text, and there are no existing bindings for closing this window. C-c C-t is defined in the merlin-mode-map, which is not present in the opened buffer.

Comment: Creating the function to close the window is fairly easy - working out where to bind it is the question. Do you switch to the window when it opens (or does the mode move you to the window) or does the cursor stay in the window where you issue the C-c C-t?

Comment: It stays in the original window.

Comment: OK, well that means you wil not be able to use 'q' if that letter is used in merlin mode (either a self-inserting or bound to a command). You would have to give it a modifier ie. C-<something> or put it into the merlin keymap i.e. C-c C-q. The problem with that is you may as well just type C-x 1, which will bury the buffer i.e. close the window. You could bind delete-other-windows to a function key - do this with global-set-key and it will always be available so you can just hit it to close all but the current window from any window.

Answer (score 1):

There are hooks, which are not mode-specific. For example

```
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'DWIM)
```

or

```
(add-hook 'post-command-hook #'DWIM)
```

Then

```
(defun DWIM ()
  (when (string= MyPrefferedName (buffer-name (get-buffer (current-buffer))))
    DoWhatIWant))
```

or

```
(defun DWIM ()
      (when (buffer-live-p MyPrefferedBuffer)
        DoWhatIWant))
```

Comment: The problem is the buffer is not switched into, so it's not the current-buffer.

Comment: @Isaac If a specific keybinding should be active in a certain buffer, this only makes sense if it is current. AFAIU it only might be set then.